# Python can't access second element in list IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

I have a text file formatted like this:

```
Jeff:2
Bob:7
Adam:4
```

I've read the data from the text file and created a list for each line. So that it looks like this when I run the program.

```
['']
['Jeff', '2']
['Bob', '7']
['Adam', '4']
```

However I want to assign a variable to the first and second elements in the lists so that I can sort the integers from highest to lowest but it keep getting an error, which I can't solve.

Here is my code:

```
if choice == 1:
    f = open("group1.txt", 'r')
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip("\n").lstrip().rstrip().split(":")
        print(line)
        name = line[0]
        scores = int(line[1])

        print(scores)
```

It gives the error

```
scores = line[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't work the number is the second element within the list "line"

How can I fix this? Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: You showed it yourself; your first list has just *one element*; the line started out empty. As such there is no `line[1]` element.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you're going for with the repeated `strip` calls - `line.strip().split(':')` would do the same thing.

Comment: So `line.strip("\n")` will delete any whitespace before and after a string as well as newline characters? @PeterDeGlopper

Comment: `line.strip("\n")` will not, but `line.strip()` will. The default behavior is to remove all whitespace, including `\n`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's an empty line in the file. In fact you already pointed out that the output contains a:

```
['']
```

Which is a list with **1** element, thus `line[1]` ges out of bounds.

Just change the code to ignore empty or blank lines:

```
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if ':' not in line:
        # can't be splitted in two using : as separator
        continue
    name, scores = line.split(':')
```

Comment: @CizzleP Delete what list?

Comment: @KyleStrand I meant the first list in my code as that was causing the error

Answer (score 2):

Look at the list output you produced:

```
['']
['Jeff', '2']
['Bob', '7']
['Adam', '4']
```

See anything special about that first one? That one was produced by an *empty line*; there was no `:` character to split on so there is just the one element left; devoid of whitespace only the empty string remained.

Handle that exception:

```
line = line.strip().split(":")
print(line)
try:
    name = line[0]
    scores = int(line[1])
except IndexError:
    # not enough elements in the line
    continue

print(scores)
```

The `try..except` catches the exception thrown when there are not enough elements, and `continue` then skips to the next line.

There is also no need to separately strip newlines, then just the left-hand side, then just the right-hand side; one `str.strip()` call takes care of all three in one step.

Comment: I'd use to regular expressions to find all numbers and zip them to all names.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: splitting and conversion is an excellent way to handle this. Regular expressions are overkill in this case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so this code catches the IndexError with the `except ` statement and then just moves on to the next line  and assigns the variables instead of breaking ?

Comment: @CizzleP: exactly. If there is an exception the rest of the loop is ignored and we continue to process the next line instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your file is an empty line, so:

```
line = ''
line = line.strip("\n").lstrip().rstrip().split(":") # still ''
# note that this is just line.strip().split(":")
print(line)
# prints an empty string
name = line[0] # name is an empty string
scores = int(line[1])
# there is no second index in an empty string.
```

The usual way to deal with this is:

```
for line in f:
    if not line:
        # edge case of an empty line
        continue
    # rest of your code
```